# How to convert a stream before it reaches StreamBuilder?

Tags: flutter, dart, stream-builder

I'd like to convert a stream before it reaches StreamBuilder, but have no idea what that would look like. As an test, I created the simple countdown below. What I'd like to do is give CountDownConversion to StreamBuilder, but if I uncomment it, I get compile errors. I've been reading up on streams and StreamBuilder, but haven't seen anyone doing this type of conversion before StreamBuilder. If someone could clue me in, I'd appreciate it.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Stream<int> countDown() async* {
    int i = 42;
    while (true) {
      await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
      yield i--;
      if (i == 0) break;
    }
  }

// Stream<String> countDownConverter() {
//   final number = countDown();
//   return number.toString();
// }

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
    stream: countDown(), // <- want countDownConverter() here
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active) {
        final String count = snapshot.data.toString();
        return Text(count, style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4);
      } else return Text('Working...');
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: use `Stream.map` method, like `var mapped = countDown().map((i) => i.toString());` now you can use `stream: mapped`

Comment: Thanks @pskink. My actual use case is converting json from Firestore into my local models. I'd like to do the conversion in my ViewModel rather than having json in my Flutter View code, if that makes any sense

Comment: thats why i wrote `var mapped = countDown().map((i) => i.toString());` and not `stream: countDown().map((i) => i.toString()),` - simply call `map` method where you are getting your firestore `Stream` (bloc, provider etc) - in other words: map your firestore `Stream` into another `Stream`

Comment: Ah. Perfect. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert `countDownConverter` to an async generator as well and use `await for` to have it listen to `countDown`:

```dart
Stream<String> countDownConverter() async* {
  await for (int n in countDown()) {
    yield n.toString();
  }
}
```

Though ideally instead of writing a conversion method, you could simply use `map` on the stream itself:

```dart
StreamBuilder(
  stream: countDown().map((i) => i.toString()),
  ...
),
```

Comment: Thanks @Abion47. That's perfect. When you say ideal use `map`, is that because its fewer keystrokes or is there another advantage?

Comment: @buttonsrtoys It's ideal because when there's a prebuilt function that serves your purposes, don't reinvent the wheel.